# Figuring out firestore with ngrx

Tags: firebase, ngrx, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I seem to be stuck on this, as there is not many guides or tutorials out there on how to use firestore with ngrx.

Lets say we have list of organisations, all of these will be used in 2 componants, componantA and componentB.

1. I can make an effect, that takes an LOAD_ACTION that merges the collection valuechanges observable and also map it out to LOAD_ACTION_SUCCESS for each component.

Now everytime there is a change, LOAD_ACTION_SUCCESS will be called, saving our data to each of their store state.

But this requires the component to dispatch LOAD_ACTION to start with, which might seem a bit errornous for REAL_TIME_DATA, as it will continue to update after. Even when not used.

2. I could just connect the services observable of valuechanges (the same as LOAD_ACTION does), in the component itself. It will not have state saved, but the Firebase observable is kinda like a Store (as long as it isnt saved on client), so if it has already gotten the data, it is already there.

Not using up 2 copies of data for state anymore.

Which leads me to:

3. Should it maybe have a store for the 'collection' from the service, which both components get data from, such as there is not multiple copies of that state everywhere it is used.

Any information or guidence to help me get further is appreciated, i seem to be stuck at such a trivial issue, obviously i can keep coding, but rather want it correct.

As dealing with real time data seems to be confusing me when it comes to ngrx.

Examples will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I just wrote a little [blog](https://medium.com/@michael.warneke/ngrx-get-data-from-firestore-part-1-6f6688946c46) about that issue where I want to compare the different ways to connect Firestore with NGRX.

Basically, you can map the valueChanges() actions to your store actions and the store will be in sync. I used an effect doing, but that can be in an service as well.

```
  @Effect()
  getData$ = this.dataDb.getFakeDataStateChanges().pipe(
    mergeMap(actions => actions),
    map(action => {
      return {
        type: `[FirstData] ${action.type}`,
        payload: { id: action.payload.doc.id, ...action.payload.doc.data() }
      };
    })
  );
```

Where the actions are like

```
export enum FirstActionTypes {
  FIRST_DATA_ADDED = '[FirstData] added',
  FIRST_DATA_MODIFIED = '[FirstData] modified',
  FIRST_DATA_REMOVED = '[FirstData] removed'
}
```

and the reducer handles the data

```
export function firstReducer(state: State = initialState, action: FirstAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FirstActionTypes.FIRST_DATA_ADDED: 
      return firstAdapter.addOne(action.payload, state);

    case FirstActionTypes.FIRST_DATA_MODIFIED:
      return firstAdapter.updateOne(
      {
        id: action.payload.id,
        changes: action.payload
      },
      state
    );

    case FirstActionTypes.FIRST_DATA_REMOVED:
      return firstAdapter.removeOne(action.payload.id, state);

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is along the lines fireship.io recommends doing it. I still think using a service is cleaner. I am looking for a solution which separates the component completely from the backend.